# How does Causal Forest make small/narrow effect estimates comparing to empirical data?

Tags: mixed-model, econometrics, causality

I created a [CausalForest (from econml)](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/_autosummary/econml.grf.CausalForest.html) model to estimate non-binary outcomes (similar to daily sales amount) given covariates and a binary treatment. I evaluate the model using the following procedure:

1. use the model, denoted $\tau(X, w)$, to estimate the effects for my dataset;
2. rank and bin the estimated effects of the units/examples from high to low;
3. for each bin $b$ of size $n_b$, compute its estimated effect as the mean of model's estimates of all units in that bin, i.e. $\hat{\tau}_b = {1 \over n_b} \sum_{i \in b}{\tau}(X_i, w=1)$;
4. for each bin $b$, compute its "empirical" effect by subtracting the mean outcomes of the treated from that of the untreated, i.e. $\tau_b = E[Y_b(1)] - E[Y_b(0)]$.

I found that the effects estimated by the CF has rather small values (small mean effect  and small variance) of every bin compared to the "empirical" effects of the corresponding bin.) However, the estimates seem to be consistent in the sense that bins with higher estimated effects also have higher empirical effects as computed above; only the magnitudes of the estimates are too small. Further it does not seem to be an overfitting issue since the same is observed for both training set and validation/test sets.

It is said that applying typical ML algorithms to causal effect estimate may [bias the estimated effects to zero](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/22-Debiased-Orthogonal-Machine-Learning.html#more-econometrics-may-be-needed). Does the same happen to CausalForest? What would be the remedy?